# Why is active hover CSS only working on a few of these list items

Tags: css

I am combining two fonts in order to display all the needed icons in a Social Icon list.  The hover effect is working correctly on the original icon font, but the one icon that I have that is part of another font is not displaying the same behavior.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Correct item:

```
    <li class="et-social-icon et-social-instagram">
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/rattletree/" class="icon">
<span><?php esc_html_e( 'Instagram', 'Divi' ); ?></span>
</a>
</li>
```

CSS for the correct item:

```
.et-social-icon a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 300ms ease 0s;
}
```

Incorrect item:

```
<li class="et-social-icon fa fa-soundcloud fa-2x">
<a href="https://soundcloud.com/rattletree" class="icon">
<span><?php esc_html_e( 'Instagram', 'Divi' ); ?></span>
</a>
</li>
```

I copied the above css to the new class:

```
.fa-soundcloud a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 300ms ease 0s;
}
```

Though the site is in development, I do have it live here if anyone wants to take a look:
http://rattletree.com/wordpress2/home/

The icons are both in the header and the footer.  The Soundcloud icon is the one that is not working correctly.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hm... ".fa-soundcloud a' is different than 'fa fa-soundcloud fa-2x', whatever the hell that means anyway. So, my guess from what you posted is that you have the wrong name in your CSS.
Edit: never mind, didn't see the spaces.

Comment: Try this 
`.fa-soundcloud:hover:before {
    color: #2ea3f2;transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme uses the `:before` pseudo-element of the `li`s to display the icon, while FontAwesome uses the `:before` of the anchor to do it. You need to move the content (and apply the font-family) from the li element to the anchor, so the theme styles apply. Here's the fix (I also added some rules for the height difference between the two fonts):

```
.et-social-icon.fa-soundcloud.fa-2x:before {
    content: "";
}
.et-social-icon.fa-2x {
    font-size: 0;
}
.et-social-icon.fa-2x a {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 24px
}
.et-social-icon.fa-soundcloud a:before {
    content: "\f1be";
    font-family:FontAwesome !important;
}
```

Comment: What happens if he wants to add in another fontAwesome icon in his list of social links. He has to then overwrite and manually add the content for that everytime?

Comment: @partypete You're thinking of a lil patch that would apply to the theme and make `.fa-` icons work out of the box? Nice idea but I don't see it happening without js. I'll think of it.

Comment: if we are only talking about one icon then what's the point of including the entire font awesome font? Better off just including that one as an svg.

Comment: No, i'm thinking of a script that takes all the `:before`s from `li`s and puts them on the `a`s, on the fly. The problem is javascript cannot set content of pseudo-elements (they are not part of DOM). However, they can be read. So I'm guessing I can use js to make a list of them, write a  style tag and append it to head. I like the idea you had and I definitely want to do it. Problem is I don't have time for myself today. Worst case scenario I'll do it over the weekend. Maybe wrap it as a small wp-plugin: divi-social-fontawesome or smth. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So with your `et-social-icon` icons, the content for each is being placed in the pseudo :before element inside the link `a` but `fa-soundcloud` is adding the content in the pseudo :before element in the list item `li`, outside of the link. So the color change on hover is still effecting the link, but the link isn't where the icon is.

So add this `.fa-soundcloud:hover:before` to the css selector that changes your color to `color: #2ea3f2;`

Comment: While technically correct and fixing the problem in this particular case, your solution is too specific and breaks theme functionality. If one chooses to change the theme color the soundcloud icon will remain blue on hover.

Comment: No it doesn't. Have a look at the style sheet currently in use on the site. All I'm suggesting is adding that selector to the group that is currently in play to change the links to blue on hover.

Comment: You probably haven't worked with Divi. When you change the color scheme, a different css is loaded. Your solution would require to also change the custom CSS after you change the color scheme  of the theme, in Settings.. Basically, your code breaks the "*change the color scheme without knowing how to code*" paradigm of this theme.

Comment: The issue with this solution was that color change is not the same in the header and footer.  This answer made the color change be the same for both header and footer.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Yep ok I see that in regards to working hand in hand with the theme my solution doesn't address the issue well enough.

Comment: @Joel Yes so you would have to update the css twice (or more depending on how many instances of different coloured links there are) so i can see how this isn't ideal.